# My svg outline is not exactly on the svg edges

Tags: html, css, object, svg, size

[image]

I'd like my sizing and placments to be very clean.

My SVG outline is not exactly on it's edges. I can't put it in the place I want.

```
<div id="ticket-container">
  <div id="ticket">
    <object data="ticket.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="ticket">
            x
    </object>
  </div>
</div>`
```

```
#ticket-container{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block ;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box ;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
  color: whitesmoke !important; 

}
#ticket{
  background-color: #e00808;
  width: 30%;
  height: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#ticket-svg{
  height: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: its in the pic above

Comment: We'd need to see the markup of ticket.svg. An image isn't any help.